# Load multiple js files all at once on ajax success - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

so right now I have this code. on ajax success it dynamically loads my js files. but my point here is.. is there any way where I can load them all at once without typing them one by one? by means like folder/*.js then it will load all js files inside that folder. here is my example code.

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(document).on("click", "a[rel=tab]", function(e) {
    // e.preventDefault();
    $e = $(e);
    pageurl = $(this).attr('href');
    $.ajax({
        url: pageurl + '?rel=tab',
        success: function(data) {

            var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
            var jquery = document.createElement("script");
            jquery.type = "text/javascript";
            jquery.src = base_url + "/assets/bower_components/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js";
            head.appendChild(jquery);

            var js = document.createElement("script");
            js.type = "text/javascript";
            js.src = base_url + "/assets/bower_components/datatables.net-bs/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js";
            head.appendChild(js);

            var jsn = document.createElement("script");
            jsn.type = "text/javascript";
            jsn.src = base_url + "/assets/js/newscript.js";
            head.appendChild(jsn);
            jsn.onload = function() {
                $('#inside').html(data);
            }
        }
    });

    //to change the browser URL to 'pageurl'
    if (pageurl != window.location) {
        window.history.pushState({ path: pageurl }, '', pageurl);
    }
    return false;
});

$(window).bind('popstate', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: location.pathname + '?rel=tab',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#inside').html(data);
        }
    });
});
});
```

Comment: No. Each separate file requires a separate HTTP request to be made in order to load it, or in the case of script files, a separate `<script>` tag to be defined. Your only other option is to use a build tool to combine all your script files into one for deployment, and then just load that one combined file. You can't specify a folder because HTTP has no concept of folders. A URL is assumed to be some kind of resource on the server. There's nothing to say that has to map to an actual file or folder on the server's disk. It could point to nothing, and then get routed to a script via a framework

Comment: And there's no way to enumerate files in a folder on the server, for basically the same reasons

Comment: On a side note, since you're using jQuery, you could just use `$.getScript(url, callback)`

Comment: oh I see. well that explained it. thank you anyways. :) @ADyson

Comment: yeah. I'm trying to use the $.when() $.done() and load the scripts inside but it's not working for me. well I'll just stick with what I'm working now I guess @ManuelOtto

Comment: @ManuelOtto Although undocumented getScript returns a promise so better to leave the callback where it belongs, in the past.

Comment: Try Axios and pure js, instead of $fAther

Comment: @HMR Promises are just fancy wrappers around callbacks.

Answer (score 2):

Question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47256603/getscript-function-working-but-doesnt-get-some-of-the-css) with the following code:

```
const getScripts = 
  resources => {
    jQuery.when.apply(
      null
      ,resources.map(
        resource =>
          $.getScript(base_url + resource)
        )
    )
;

getScripts(["url1","url2"])
.then(
  () => console.log("finished loading scripts")
  ,err => console.warn("Failed:",err)
);
```

I think you need to rethink your design though, loading a bunch of scripts again. All you need is set some content through xhr (not a big fan of using xhr to request html parts) and initialize the content with script.

Instead of reloading all the scripts you should call a function that will initialize the content.